# How to build static ios framework in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have Objective-C++ project, it contains "include" directory with headers, and 2 folders with .a and .lib files (one folder for i386 and other one for arm). How can I combine all of it to one .a file or Static iOS Framework (for xcode6 https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/raw/master/screenshot.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

lipo can help to solve the question,
but need to add -create parameter.

```
lipo -create simulator.a device.a -output universe.a
```

Then check universe.a

```
lipo -info universe.a
```

If built in Xcode 6, expect output is "Architectures in the fat file: universe.a are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64 "